# Designer & Resx doesn't see form after import

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

I created a new project and imported a few user controls and forms from another project. I did an add existing item through VS2019.

I am now getting this:

[image]

When I open up a control or form, it shows it blank. If I right click on the form/control and goto code, it takes me to the proper place.

This seems to affect the designer more than anything but I need the designer to modify the controls on the user control or forms.

The namespaces are correct, that was the first thing I checked.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

**EDIT#1**

I checked the project file and it seems to be right, though, I might be overlooking something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{90E9229F-A341-48A6-9951-3373A87B5D19}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>SSS.SuburbanRemoteOperations</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>RemoteOps</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>SSS.SuburbanRemoteOperations.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AppStyle.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BaseForm.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="BaseForm.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\CustomerInquiryBannerControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\CustomerInquiryBannerControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\CustomerInquiryControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\CustomerInquiryControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\FooterControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\FooterControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheckCommentsControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheckCommentsControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheckMenuControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheckMenuControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheck_TestControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheck_TestControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\HeaderControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\HeaderControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\MainControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\MainControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controls\SettingsControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Controls\SettingsControl.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CurrentCustomer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Forms\RequestSupport.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\RequestSupport.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainMenu.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainMenu.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Miscellaneous\Logging.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="BaseForm.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\CustomerInquiryBannerControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\CustomerInquiryControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\FooterControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheckCommentsControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheckMenuControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\GasCheck\GasCheck_TestControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\HeaderControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\MainControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Controls\SettingsControl.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\RequestSupport.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="MainMenu.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you select all files from the `Add -> Existing Item` interface? You should select only the main `.cs` file. You can see this better if you copy a whole UserControl (3 files, usually) inside a Project, in Solution Explorer click the `Show All Files` button. It will show you just the main File, the other files are shown if you expand its node. I.e., VS rebuilds the partial files on its own.

Comment: Did you loose the Initilaize() statement?

Comment: @Jimi I'll delete them and readd them per your instructions. Thanks!

Comment: @jdweng no it's still there in all of the .cs files

Comment: InitializeComponent(); is run as part of the form constructor and adds the controls to the form.  It is possible the  InitializeComponent(); is failing.  Try putting a break point on line after  InitializeComponent(); and see if you get there.  The form may be behind the other forms and that is why you are not seeing the form.

Comment: @Jimi That was it, though, if I add multiple user controls or forms at once, it doesn't work. I had to add them individually for it to work. Thank again!

Comment: If you use `Add Existing Item`. If you copy all the files inside the Project and, as mentioned, click the `Show All Files` button in Solution Explorer (click twice if already pushed), you can select multiple *main* elements, then right click and pick `Include in Project` from the contextual menu. The integrity of the correlated partial files is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the solution to this problem:

We cannot select all files from the `Add->Existing` Item interface. We should just select the main `.cs` file.

If you copy multiple files at once, VS will rebuild some of the files by itself, which can lead to failure.

If copying all files in the project, click `Show All Files` in `Solution Explorer` to expand all nodes.

Select as many main elements as you need and include them in the project so that the full performance of the relevant part of the file is preserved.